# RouteLink Not work in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my application I allow user to redirect to htttps://www.google.co.in from my application.

for that I used RouteLink.I know we can also do it by actionLink.

CODE:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Google",null,"https","www.google.co.in", null, null, new { @style = "color:red" })
```

Generated HTML

```
     <a style="color:red" href="https://www.google.co.in/Home/RouteLink">Google</a>
```

And I also add Routing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
              name: "RouteLink",
              url: "Home/RouteLink",
              defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "RouteLink" });  

         routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =   
             UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

     }
```

So my Question is why I get anchor tag Like above? and If RouteLink does not allow to redirect to another domain than why It had overloaded method that accept hostname and protocol?

Comment: What is the use of `RouteLink` when a regular hyperlink (`a`) should do?

Comment: yes I can also do it using simple anchor tag and I can also do it using @Html.ActionLink() but why @html.RouteLink has a overloaded method which acccept hostname and protocol? and why i can't redirect to another domain using RouteLink?

Comment: I dont know about the reason behind hostname. However, the RouteLink doc says that it generates link for a virtual path.

Answer (score 0):

> So my Question is why I get anchor tag Like above

Because you specifically tell it so on the 3rd and 4th parameter of RouteLink.

> If RouteLink does not allow to redirect to another domain than why It
>   had overloaded method that accept hostname and protocol?

Because that's not what you use it for. `RouteLink` and it's sister method `ActionLink` are used to generate valid (or safe) links within your application.

If you want to link to an outside application/website then just use the anchor tag.

Comment: so you means i can't do it using routeLink?

Comment: To an external site, you can't. [See this blog post to learn more how it is used](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/21/named-routes-to-the-rescue.aspx)

Comment: Than why It has Overloaded method Like @Html.RouteLink(linkText,routeName,protocol,hostName,fragment,routeValues,htmlAttributes)

Comment: That really is not what RouteLink is for. Have you read the blog? RouteLink is really useful in cases where you want a **specific** route to be picked up by the engine. So it works **on your application** and not on some **outer application**.

Comment: Btw, if you want to be fancy with and don't want to type the `a` tag directly then build your own extension method.